# How to identify script id associated with Google drive file via API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I have a requirement whereby I need to programmatically go through all files in a users Google drive and identify any associated scripts.  I can get all of the files using the Drive API;

- list method of https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files

and I can get the specific script content by using the Apps script API

- projects.get method of https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{scriptId}

however, this call requires the input of a scriptId which I can't seem to identify from the information defined against the file.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get this information either using the approach above or an alternative one?  I'm just looking to identify the content of all scripts in all files.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are required to also retrieve the file content of the container-bound script, unfortunately, in the current stage, it cannot be achieve yet. You can retrieve the content from the standalone script using Google APIs, because the file ID of standalone script can be retrieved by API. But in the current stage, the file ID of the container-bound script cannot be retrieved yet. By this, the content of bound script cannot be retrieved using only APIs. How about this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have same question as @James. I've dived in the response from the API and API docs but found no way to get the script id from drive file/google docs file :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getFilesByTipe](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbytypemimetype) function from DriveApp, and search for GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT type. I found it in [this](https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsToPdu5x3ElkFk/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/drive/Pdu5x3ElkFk) post from Google Support:

```
function main() { 
  for(var f, F = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT); f = F.hasNext()?F.next():null;) 
    Logger.log("Name: " + f.getName() + " ID: " + f.getId());
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks, however what I ultimately need to do is get the content of the script itself, I'm not sure if this will provide this level of detail?

Comment: I found [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent) but I couldn't find anything to do the same in Appscript. Also I'm not sure if it returns all the information you need.

Comment: That does do exactly what I need, however, it requires a script id and I was hoping that there would be some way of getting that script id from the file, but I can't find that, this is the piece of the puzzle that is missing.

Comment: @JamesPhillips did you manage to figure out how to programmatically retrieve the script Id? If so, would you mind sharing some insight? Many thanks

Comment: Hi, @Drive2blue, apologies for not coming back sooner, the requirement went away due to no longer being required, and I never found a solution, so unfortunately there is nothing further I can offer you I'm afraid.